# How to make Batch file wait for prompt to execute next command?

Tags: batch-file, heroku, scheduled-tasks

In my batch file I can use "pause" to prompt the user for input. But how do I make the batch file wait for a remote event to execute and supply a prompt before executing a second command?

Here is my use case:

I would like to set up a batch file to access my Heroku-hosted application's console and run a command.

Manually, I can run these commands:

`heroku run console --app appname
Event.where(title: nil).map(&:destroy)
exit`

I am trying to run a bash script on Windows task scheduler.

The first command goes ok, and I am able to open the Heroku console. But then the console just sits open and the batch file does not execute the command, `Event.where(title: nil).map(&:destroy)`.

How do I tell the batch file to wait for the console to open and then execute the command and then exit?